# why this mongoose text search doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Even though I have similar data in collection, result always comes back empty. I have ingredients in array[object]. That means qty:1 unit:spoon ing:salt and I want only `ing` to be searchable. I have mongoose debug enabled and it shows:

`Mongoose: recipes.ensureIndex({ 'Ingridients.ing': 'text' }) { background: true, safe: undefined }`

This is the code:

```
var RecipesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: {type: String, required: true},
  Desc: String,
  Ingridients: [{qty:Number, unit:String, ing:{ type: String, index: "text" } }],
  created: { type: Date }
});

Recipe.find({ $text : { $search : "salt egg potato peper" } }, 
            { score : { $meta: "textScore" }
    })
    .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
    .exec(function(err, recipe) {
        // callback
        if(err) console.log(err);
            res.render('list', { recipes: recipe });
});
```

Comment: Have you created a text index? If yes, how? If no: do this now!

Comment: i got it working on localhost but doesn't work on mongolab.com

Answer (score 0):

after i tried on localhost and it worked, switched on mongolab.com by dropping and recreating collection and indexes again. it was not able to index correctly

```
ERR: planner returned error: need exactly one text index for $text query',  code: 17007
```